# TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, transactions

I have following dao:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void add(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

it is invokes from

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {    

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public ModelAndView test() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("34r");

        userDao.add(user);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        model.addObject("userList", null);
        return model;

    }

}
```

in browser I try to access to this link

And finally I get following stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/SpringMvcHibernateXML] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started] with root cause
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:172)
```

I have following configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not do `session.getTransaction().commit();` this, the @transactional will take care of it. Remove it, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you.. I found it useful

Answer (score 1):

where you begin the transaction. i can't see this line
session.beginTrainsaction();
once you begin the transaction then only you can commit and rollback